# How to give Administrator Privileges to my VSPackage?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

I've developed a `VSPackage` for Visual Studio, which needs to copy some files to *Visual Studio's Installation Path*.

If I Run Visual Studio as Administrator (when using my installed VSPackage). It can copy files with no errors.

When I run Visual Studio normally, I get `Access to the path ... is denied` error.

**Question**

How can I give my `VSPackage` to admin privileges even when the Visual Studio is being run as a normal user.

Or at least how can I invoke something like this:

[image]

Comment: Install your extension as an MSI

Comment: I answered one of your other questions some days ago; it answers this question as well... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30874782/how-get-the-current-running-visual-studio-installation-path-from-vspackage

Comment: Actually that didn't work for me. Thanks tho

Comment: @Matze I think you better copy your answer here

Comment: @AliSharabiani And then you´re changing the question´s title again to something else and make my answer irrelavant? No, not again my friend (-;

Comment: @Matze no, previously someone has changed the title of that question, I re-edit it. Also I think talking about these things here is not constructive :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package is a .dll (loaded on a process), not an .exe (a process), and therefore it cannot have different privileges than its process (Visual Studio, that is, devenv.exe). What your package can do is to launch a different process with admin rights. See my article:

[HOWTO: Launch a process with admin rights from a Visual Studio add-in on Windows Vista or higher.](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2009/MZ2009007.aspx)

That said, it is a very wrong approach to do this to copy files to the VS installation path. That should be done by the setup of your package (.msi), not by your package.

On the one hand, if it is done by the package once installed, the user could deny the elevation prompt and the files would not be copied and your installation would be incomplete. Can your package run properly without those files?

On the other hand, if the user denies the elevation prompt to install the package, it wouldn't be installed at all, which is a more clean approach.

Comment: My VSPackage updatins some code snippets and xml schema files in Visual Studio. To do this, the package should download the files from a server (whenever new files are available), and copy them in Visual Studio's folder.Also every time user can force update snippets and schemas by clicking a command on the menu bar. Snippets are being updated regularly on the server . That being said we copy files more than once. So msi cannot be an option. What do you think the best approach for implementing this is? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure about xml schema files, but about code snippets Visual Studio allows per-user code snippets that are stored in C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Visual Studio <version>\Code Snippets. I guess there must be an API to import them there, and it shouldn't require admin rights because they are per-user.

Comment: If admin rights are required, then the only way is a second process that copies them, with an elevation prompt.