# VSIX - path to C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Is there an easy way to find the correct path to (VS version independent) "C:\Users\< user >\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\" from within the VSIX code?

I know that I can use the "%UserProfile%" placeholder for the first part, but how can I detect the correct Visual Studio folder itself, without creating a mapping myself?

Comment: What are you trying to do, and how your question is related to VSIX?

Comment: @TWT, Do you mean that you want to get the current running Visual Studio's installation path?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30874782/how-get-the-current-running-visual-studio-installation-path-from-vspackage

Comment: No, that's another directory.